# How to play sound at specific time in Java?

Tags: java

I am making a alarm clock program where the user enters a time and at that time a sound will play. However I cannot figure out a simple way of actually playing the sound at the right time. Any thoughts on how to achieve this ? I will provide the source code

Code:

```
package alarmClock;

import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;



public class AlarmTImer {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    // audio source
    File audioFile = new File("C:\\Users\\zayaa\\Documents\\alarm Clock Beeps Sound Effect.wav");
    AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    
    // String response = scanner.next();
    /* clip.open(audioStream);
    clip.start(); */
    
    
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
    String time = LocalTime.now().format(dtf);
    // LocalDateTime currentTime = LocalDateTime.parse(time, dtf);
    LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.parse(time, dtf);
    System.out.println(time);
    
    String userInp = "";
    System.out.println("Enter hour for alarm (24hr): ");
    String hour = scanner.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Enter mins for alarm: ");
    String mins = scanner.nextLine();
    userInp = userInp + hour + ":" + mins;
    System.out.println("User inputted: " + userInp);
    
    LocalTime userTime = LocalTime.parse(userInp, dtf);
    


    System.out.println();
        
    while (!currentTime.equals(userTime)) {
        Duration timeRemaining = Duration.between(currentTime, userTime);
        long seconds = timeRemaining.getSeconds(); // no get minutes function
        long minutes = ((seconds % 3600) / 60); // conversion
        System.out.println("Time remaining: " + minutes + " mins");
            
        if (currentTime.equals(userTime)) {
            System.out.println("The time has come.. ");
            clip.open(audioStream);
            clip.start();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDateTime alarm =
    LocalDateTime.now()
        .withHour(Integer.parseInt(hour))
        .withMinute(Integer.parseInt(minute))
        .withSecond(0);

long secondsInBetween = Duration.between(now, alarm).getSeconds();

try {
  // sleep for milliseconds
  Thread.sleep(secondsInBetween * 1000);
  // play sound
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  System.err.println("Interrupted!");
}
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep` is not wall clock accurate over long periods of time.

Comment: @Udo Klimaschewski Why do you use Thread.sleep? also why are you using LocalDateTime instead of LocalTime?

Comment: @zkwho Thread.sleep() does not use the CPU, the program just pauses for the specified time.

Comment: @zkwho You can also use LocalTime, but maybe you want to add some logic to set the alarm for the next day? E.g. set the alarm to tomorrow 7am at 8pm today?

Answer (score 0):

1. Note that you are never actually updating `currentTime`, so the condition will always be false.
2. Also note that the condition in your `while` loop is the same as the `break` condition. if for some reason the current time were to update before the nested `if` was reached, you would simply leave the loop and end the program without triggering the alarm.
3. You are using `time.equals()`, so if the time has passed in between checks - it's infinite loop time. Use `time.isBefore()` or `time.isAfter()`.
4. Lastly - this program is very wasteful as the cpu keeps working and calculating until the alarm time. See Udo's answer for a better solution.

Comment: Thank you for making me realise this. However, can you please elaborate on the 2nd point you made as in which conditions would the current time update before the conditional statement? This will help me to understand further . Thanks

Comment: @zkwho imagine that the time is 1ms before `userTime` as you reach the `if` statement - you won't enter the `if` block. Then time ticks - `currentTime` equals `userTime` and the `while` condition is now false - you will skip the `while` block.